# Android: pass current activity to other with function and use it as target for back button

Tags: android, android-activity, view

i have baseActivity class that extend Activity in this way:

```
class baseActivity extends Activity {

    public void gotolist(View v){

        Intent list = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), list.class);
        String pkg=getPackageName();

        list.putExtra(pkg + ".cat", v.getContentDescription());
        startActivity(list);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
    }
}
```

In the template fileS in the View that i want use the code:

```
android:contentDescription="32"
android:onClick="gotolist"
```

QUESTION: i want send to the list.class (activity) the actual activity info, so that when clicking on custom button in list.class i can set it to go back to origin activity.

I'm quite new on Android and on OOP, so i need help :).
Thank you for reading. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method startActivityOnResult( intent );

Here is a good example:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Thank you, but seems to much different from my code. Isn't a fastest way to add some code to my?

Comment: I do not need to get a contact in example. I only need to pass with that gotolist() the name of current activity that i use in the target activity for a "back" custom button...